# Angular hide div on click function

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

i am new to angular and typescript and i need to hide div section *ngIf="stu.notes != null" on save button click.
i can display the respective divs when clicked on the respective buttons, but i am not able to hide the other one.

Can anyone hep me out here.
Thanks in advance.

**HTML File:**

```html
<nb-accordion-item-body>
   <div class="row">
      <div *ngIf="notes_area != null">
         <h5> <span class="col-md-8" style="font-weight : bold; font-size : 16px;" 
            [innerHTML]="notes_area"></span>
         </h5>
         <br/> 
      </div>
      <div  class="col-md-3" *ngFor = "let stu of studentData">
         <div *ngIf="stu.notes != null" >
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8">
                  <br/>
                  <h5 style="font-weight : bold;" > {{stu?.notes.slice(3,-4)}}
                  </h5>
                  <br/>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <div class="row" *ngIf="addNote == true">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <tinymce [(ngModel)] = "notes" ></tinymce>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <button nbButton (click)="saveNotes()">Save</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</nb-accordion-item-body>
```

**.ts File:**

```js
saveNotes() {
 this.api.saveNotes(this.my_app_data[0].app_id,this.notes).subscribe(data => {
    this.notes_area = data['data'];
    console.log(this.app_id);  
    console.log('log',this.notes);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can use only `*ngIf="notes_area"` it would work, and same goes for `*ngIf="addNote"` instead of `*ngIf="addNote == true"`

Comment: @KamranKhatti it will work same on your soution.... what i want is to hide the whole div when *ngIf="stu.notes != null" on save button

Comment: Which div you want to hide you are already using this condition `*ngIf="stu.notes != null"` on one of the div

Comment: @KamranKhatti i want to hide the div for condition `*ngIf="stu.notes != null"`  on save button click.  Both divs on there respective condition works fine but need t hide this div here  `<div  class="col-md-3" *ngFor = "let stu of studentData">
                    <div *ngIf="stu.notes != null" >
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                              <br/>
                             <h5 style="font-weight : bold;" > {{stu?.notes.slice(3,-4)}}
                             </h5>
               <br/>`

Comment: If you want to hide the div on save button click then create a new variable let say `showDiv = true` and inside save button use `this.showDiv=false` and use it inside if condition on that div `ngIf="showDiv"`

Comment: Did you try does it work?

Comment: @KamranKhatti impementing `*ngif="shwDiv"` on div don't work fr me..... How are you suggesting.....

Comment: At my end i was having some issue.... worked for me.